# npm-run-all -p build:* sh: 1: npm-run-all: not found npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, yaml, buildspec

[Container] 2021/05/28 16:28:06 Entering phase BUILD
[Container] 2021/05/28 16:28:06 Running command npm run build

> settl-me@1.3.0 build /codebuild/output/src979787175/src
> npm-run-all -p build:*

sh: 1: npm-run-all: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! settl-me@1.3.0 build: `npm-run-all -p build:*`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the settl-me@1.3.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-05-28T16_28_10_049Z-debug.log

[Container] 2021/05/28 16:28:10 Command did not exit successfully npm run build exit status 1
[Container] 2021/05/28 16:28:10 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2021/05/28 16:28:10 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: npm run build. Reason: exit status 1

Comment: So you dumped in some Error message, but you may have forgotten to ask a question ...

Comment: wow! SO SORRY!!!
I was trying to build and deploy a React app on aws but it was bringing this ERROR